# returning the clicked date from ttkcalendar widget

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to use this calendar widget [code](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Demo/tkinter/ttk/ttkcalendar.py) within an existing tkinter.  I want to have the clicked date returned, so that I can do things with it.  I have tried calling the pressed function like so

```
 from ttkcalendar import *
    def clicked(event):
        print cal.selection()
    ...
    root = Tk()
    cal=Calendar(mainframe)
    cal.bind("<Button-1>",clicked)
```

However this returns a Type Error: 'datetime.datetime' object not callable.  Suggestions? I am sure there is a correct way to do this...thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `selection()` has decorator `@property`, thus you should do as follows:

```
def clicked(event):
    print cal.selection
    # i.e. not cal.selection()
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Just to clarify, using the @property before the selection definition makes it an attribute?  I am fairly new to python, assumed using def name(self) would be a function like any other.

Comment: @user3883010 It does not make it property, but you can call a function as it was property.